# add key and value while call WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

need to add a key and value in Soap header while each and every call to WCF service. in code behind 
also how can we read that value in service.

in my application having 4 database at the time of login user will decide in which database he wants to login

please suggest some way to doing this

Comment: You need to be more specific about what exactly you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Can Create a method which is return a serviceclient  object like below

```
MyService.ErpServiceClient ServiceClient = new MyService.ErpServiceClient();

EndpointAddressBuilder AddressBuilder = new EndpointAddressBuilder(new EndpointAddress(GetServiceUrl()));
AddressBuilder.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("MyKey", string.Empty, (App.DataBaseKey == null) ? "" : "MyValue"));

return new MyService.ErpServiceClient(ServiceClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding, AddressBuilder.ToEndpointAddress());
```

Read key at Service side

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("MyKey", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Karan for great help

Answer (score 0):

You can create some abstract MyServiceRequestBase class and make all requests derived from it. This base class should store the DB name (or some key to identify the DB) and have only constructor accepting this parameter.

This will ensure that all WCF service methods (which follow the design rules and have request arguments object derived from your base class) pass your parameter for DB identification.